# Exact solution of scalar field cosmology with exponential potential

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

Considering a homogenious and isotropic universe described by the Robertson-Walker metric:

$$ ds^2= dt^2-a^2(t)\left[\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2(d\theta^2+\sin^2(\theta)d \phi ^2)\right]$$

and also assuming that this universe is dominated by a scalar field $\phi (t)$ and a potential of the form $ V(\phi)=V_0e^{- \lambda \phi}$ we can obtain the equations:

The $00$ component of Einstein´s equation is the Friedmann equation:

$$ H^2 + \frac{k}{a^2}= \frac{8 \pi G}{3}\left[\frac{1}{2} \dot\phi^2+V(\phi)\right]$$

where $ H(t)=\frac{\dot a(t)}{a(t)} $ is the Hubble parameter and the equation for the field $\phi$ is:

$$  \ddot\phi+3H\dot\phi-\lambda V_0e^{-\lambda \phi}=0  $$

Solving those 2 equations, considering ($8 \pi G=1$) and ($k=0$), yields the following results:

$$ a(t)=a_0 t^{P} \space \space \space, \space\space\space P=\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\space\space\space\space\space\space (1)$$
$$ \phi=\phi_0 + \frac{2}{\lambda}\ln \left( \frac{t}{t_0}\right)\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space (2)$$

I tried to obtain them but I can´t get to those solutions $(1)$ and $(2)$. Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: Could you please give a reference?

Comment: This is the closest thing I found: https: //arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0403010.pdf

Comment: Are we assuming slow-roll condition ?

Comment: If I apply slow-roll condition, I am getting something but its not exactly the written equation but sort of similar. Either I am making a calculation mistake or theres something missing, which that is why you asked the question.

Comment: It seems that an ansatz is being used for $a(t)$. I am not familiar with cosmology and i do not know what slow roll aproximation is but this is my opinion.

Comment: @Layla What did you get using the slow-roll condition?

Comment: okay I was making a calculation mistake .. I will post an answer

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh let me know when you find the answer. If you try and still cannot I can share the full solution as well.

Comment: The exponential makes the equations a mess. Change variables to $\psi=e^{-\lambda\phi}$ to get rid of it. Then try a power-law solution for $a(t)$ and $\psi(t)$.

Comment: @Layla I will try to do it again, if I cant get it I will let you know

Comment: This is a question about solving two coupled nonlinear differential equations, not a question about physics.

Answer (score 0):

So we can apply the slow-roll condition/approximation. It is given as

$$\dot{\phi}/2 \ll V(\phi)$$ When you take the derivative of both sides with respect to $\phi$, you get another identity.

$$\ddot{\phi} \ll \frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$$

Now, when you apply these conditions to the above equations you end up with

$$3H\dot{\phi} = \lambda V(\phi)~~~~(1)$$

$$3H^2 = V(\phi)~~~~(2)$$

From now on its algebra actually (which I failed at first). But let me do a couple more steps. So at this point, by inserting one in another, you'll obtain two equations

$$\dot{\phi} = \lambda H~~~~(3)$$

$$\dot{\phi} = \frac{\lambda \sqrt{3V(\phi)}}{3}~~~~(4)$$

After this, by using $H = \frac{da/dt}{a}$ in equation $(3)$

So we can apply the slow-roll condition/approximation. It is given as

$$\dot{\phi}/2 \ll V(\phi)$$ When you take the derivative of both sides with respect to $\phi$, you get another identity.

$$\ddot{\phi} \ll \frac{dV(\phi)}{d\phi}$$

Now, when you apply these conditions to the above equations you end up with

$$3H\dot{\phi} = \lambda V(\phi)~~~~(1)$$

$$3H^2 = V(\phi)~~~~(2)$$

From now on its algebra actually (which I failed at first). But let me do a couple more steps. So at this point, by inserting one in another, you'll obtain two equations

$$\dot{\phi} = \lambda H~~~~(3)$$

$$\dot{\phi} = \frac{\lambda \sqrt{3V(\phi)}}{3}~~~~(4)$$

After this, by using $H = \frac{da/dt}{a}$ in equation $(3)$.

**Let me do first $(3)$**

So we have

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = \lambda\frac{da}{dta}$$

$dt$ cancels so we are left with

$$d\phi =\lambda\frac{da}{a}$$

taking integral of both sides

$$\int_{\phi_0}^{\phi}d\phi = \int_{a_0}^a\lambda\frac{da}{a}$$

$$\phi - \phi_0 = \lambda [ln(a) - ln(a_0)] $$

Thus,

$$a(\phi) =a_0 e^{(\phi-\phi_0) / \lambda}~~~~(5)$$

**Let us look $(4)$ to find $\phi(t)$**

$$\dot{\phi} = \frac{\lambda \sqrt{3V_0e^{-\lambda \phi}}}{3}$$

Let me call $C = \frac{\lambda \sqrt{3V_0}}{3}$

so we obtain,

$$\frac{d\phi}{dt} = Ce^{(-\lambda \phi)/2}$$

$$\frac{d\phi}{e^{(-\lambda \phi)/2}} = Cdt$$

taking integral of both sides,

$$\frac{2}{\lambda}[e^{(\lambda \phi)/2}] = Ct$$

$$e^{(\lambda \phi)/2} = \frac{\lambda}{2}C(t-t_0) + e^{(\lambda \phi_0)/2} $$

Take the ln of both side

$$\frac{\lambda}{2}\phi = ln(C\frac{\lambda}{2}) + ln(t)$$

so

$$\phi = \phi_0 + \frac{2}{\lambda}ln(t)$$

now put this into (5). I know that the equations that you have wrote and this is not exactly the same but this is all I can do

Comment: I don’t believe that there is any need to assume a slow-roll condition or any other condition beyond the two differential equations in the question.

Comment: @G.Smith The OP did not write anything about it so for simplicity I just assumed that way. I am not sure how to solve it without using the slow-roll approximation. Furthermore, by using the approximation, I can obtain the equations given by the OP. So I dont think its wrong the assume the slow-roll condition. And in general, most of the inflation fields has a  slow-roll phase.

Comment: @G.Smith If you can show the solution without using the approximation, I would be happy to learn

Comment: @G.Smith I would like to know how to do it too.

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh Did you read my first comment on your question?

Comment: @Layla Could you share your full solution please?

Comment: @MicrosoftBruh have a look

Comment: @G.Smith Can you post your answer? I'm having the same doubt as them!

Comment: @RFeynman This question is currently closed. This means that no additional answers can be posted by anyone.

Comment: Can I publish the same question, so you can post your solution please? I would be thrilled if you  would publish your solution!

Comment: @G.Smith, What do you think about that?

Comment: @RFeynman I was one of the people who voted to *close* this question, so If you post a copy of it I will vote to close it *again* rather than answer it. As I explained in a comment, it is a question about solving two coupled nonlinear differential equations, not a question about physics, and thus off-topic here. It is also what we call “homework-like” and off-topic for that reason as well. However I did give a hint in another comment how to solve them.

Comment: @Layla I just saw that MicrosoftBruh had [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903116/non-linear-coupled-differential-equations) this on Math SE, where it is more appropriate. I solved it there because that site is more lenient about homework-like problems.

Comment: @RFeynman I just saw that MicrosoftBruh had [posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3903116/non-linear-coupled-differential-equations) this on Math SE, where it is more appropriate. I solved it there because that site is more lenient about homework-like problems.

Comment: @G.Smith thank you very much for letting me know!